# excel 2007 X Y lookup

Tags: excel

Good morning. I have been searching for some code either a formula or VBA to lookup values in a table. I have two tables that I am looking to migrate data from the old with the new.  Both tables are relatively the same.

```
    A     B    C    D    E
1   Store 1234 2345 3456 4567
2   1234  0    5    10   15
3   2345  5    0    20   25    
4   3456  10   20   0    35
5   4567  15   25   35   0
```

It is basically a mileage table with location to location distance. I am looking for a way to take the values from the old table into the new when the row columns dont match up exactly due to new locations added.
I know how to do a vlookup, but that dosent do what Im looking for...  I want a way for a formula or vba to something like "find Value in B2 "1234" where it intersects the value in D1 "2345" = D2 "5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do a Index and Match combo to find it. I1 = From, K1 = To you can just type in the locations into those cells and get the range out you want.

```
 =INDEX(A1:E5, MATCH(I1,A1:E1,0), MATCH(K1,A1:A5,0))
```

Comment: Yes, the 1st argument of index is the whole table. The next two arguments will be your (X,Y) that are returned from matches. The 1st argument for each match is just a way to reference something like your current location and the location you want to be.

Comment: I think I may have the array references mixed up as I am getting a #N/A error.  If my sheets are named "OLD" & "NEW" how are hte arrays labled?

Comment: If you are refrencing another sheet you will need to put something like `OLD!A1:E5`. Though if you are having trouble I would make a copy of the sheet, try to get it working on one sheet to understand it then move it. You can also select the cell the formula is in and go to the "Formulas" tab on the ribbon and find "evaluate formula" to step through the sub formulas to see where your error is.

Comment: Bmo, I see it now.  I was mistakenly selecting the entire array in teh MATCH statement in-stead of the row and column for lookup.  I have placed the Static "$" symbol for the INDEX array and the Row and COlumn Reference to complete so I can copy paste through the New array.  Thanks a BUNCH!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement IF formula to vlookup? In abstract: `=IF((vlookup)=something),do this, else)`
I would be hapy to look into this issue further, if you could provide complete `BEFORE` data and expected `AFTER` data.

Also, maybe `=DGET` would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I used this formula slightly modified and it worked fine, 
=INDEX($A$1:$G$7, MATCH(B12,$A$1:$A$7,0), MATCH(C12,$A$1:$G$1,0))

the first part of the equation is the entire table including the X and Y coords. the next two parts are the X and Y coords (you can swap these round if you wish)

so the requested information for x and y was put in cells C12 and B12 and all those cells below...
then I used the dollar symbol to fix all the other look up cells, so i could use auto fill, and entered this in E12 (this is where the result will appear.

You can see the table in the attached (or could if I was allowed to attach it). I am looking up B12 (3) in column A then looking up C12 (6) in row 1 and returning the value at the intersection (in this case returns "r").

or there would be an attachment if the stupid web page did not insist on having me obtain a 10 reputation... hopefully you get the idea...